# Does TeamCity Multi nodes setup increases the agents number?

Tags: teamcity, jetbrains-ide, cicd

Does anyone tried to use TeamCity MultiNodes setup, and know if the agents number grows with each agent?
Normally  Teamcity comes with 3 agents provided by professional edition license.
And if we need more we can buy additional license key.
Now, in case of MultiNode TeamCity setup of 3 nodes, we will have only 3 agetns, or 9 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer JetBrain answer:
In multi-node setup, the main and secondary nodes operate under the same license, so three-node setup would still have 3 agents available in absence of extra license keys.